How to recover libre sign password in nextcloud
I have forgot my signature password of libresign, when i try to reset password it asks me old password that is i don’t remember.
I need solution can anyhelp i dont remember my old password, I have admin rights also, No issue with permission

Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

I don't know libresign. Is it a hosted service? Then we can't help you. Is it software you're running yourself where you have access to the database etc.? Then it should be possible to reset the password yourself at least.
